# Alignment and Numbering of Equations in HTML

Tags: r, quarto

I would like to align some equations and have equation numbering simultaneously. When I render it to pdf, it works as expected, however, when I render it to HTML the alignment works, but no numbers appear.

**MWE**:

```
---
title: "equation example"
format: html
---

\begin{align}
x &= 2y\\
x^2 &= 2y*2y
\end{align}
```

I could use cross-referencing like this

```
$$
x = 2y
$$ {#eq-1}

$$
x^2 = 2y*2y
$$ {#eq-2}
```

but then I loose the alignment.

**Edit 1:** This is the output when the format is pdf. The equations are aligned at the &-sign. I would like to reproduce that for html as well.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround from this [issue](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/2870) that uses Sam's suggestion:

```
---
format:
  html:
    html-math-method: mathjax
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          <script>
          window.MathJax = {
            tex: {
              tags: 'ams'
            }
          };
          </script>
---


\begin{align}
x &= 2y\\
x^2 &= 2y*2y
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap them both in a `<div>` with the required style. Using the pandoc [fenced `<div>`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans) notation:

```
---
title: "equation example"
format: html
---

:::: {style="width:0; float:left;"}

$$
x = 2y
$$ {#eq-1}

$$
x^2 = 2y*2yS
$$ {#eq-2}

::::
```

Output:

[image]

N.B. I have used four colons so that you can avoid confusion if you use other `<div>` tags with three colons between these fences. But only three are required.

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for your answer. I added an edit to show what kind of alignment I would like to achieve. Any idea how to control the alignment (and as a bonus also the placement of the numbers (see the pdf-output))?

Comment: According to [here](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/eqnumbers.html) it should be a simple case of adding a `<script>MathJax.tex =  {tags: 'ams'};</script>` to your initial example, and forcing a re-render, but that doesn't seem to work for me. I don't know why not. If I were you,  I would consider posting a github issue.

Comment: It is simple and you were completely right, see my posted answer :)

Comment: Of course! In the header so need to force it to render again! Nice one.