# Mathjax equations doesn't render under each other in Quarto

Tags: html, rstudio, mathjax, quarto

I would like to show some [LaTeX Equations](https://quarto.org/docs/visual-editor/technical.html) in `Quarto`. When running the following example code, it does look right in the preview of RStudio while in the output it doesn't. Here some reproducible code:

```
---
title: "Latex equations in Quarto"
format: html
---

$$
Pr(A) = 0.5 \\
Pr(B) = 0.5
$$
```

Output preview RStudio:

[image]

Output HTML:

[image]

So it does look like the `\\` to add a break between the `$$` notation doesn't work in the output of HTML but only in the preview. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to align the equations below each other?

---

HTML file of document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"><head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="generator" content="quarto-1.2.269">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">


<title>Latex equations in Quarto</title>
<style>
code{white-space: pre-wrap;}
span.smallcaps{font-variant: small-caps;}
div.columns{display: flex; gap: min(4vw, 1.5em);}
div.column{flex: auto; overflow-x: auto;}
div.hanging-indent{margin-left: 1.5em; text-indent: -1.5em;}
ul.task-list{list-style: none;}
ul.task-list li input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 0.8em;
  margin: 0 0.8em 0.2em -1.6em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>


<script src="create_dataframe_files/libs/clipboard/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="create_dataframe_files/libs/quarto-html/quarto.js"></script>
<script src="create_dataframe_files/libs/quarto-html/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="create_dataframe_files/libs/quarto-html/tippy.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="create_dataframe_files/libs/quarto-html/anchor.min.js"></script>
<link href="create_dataframe_files/libs/quarto-html/tippy.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="create_dataframe_files/libs/quarto-html/quarto-syntax-highlighting.css" rel="stylesheet" id="quarto-text-highlighting-styles">
<script src="create_dataframe_files/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="create_dataframe_files/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="create_dataframe_files/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="quarto-bootstrap" data-mode="light">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body class="fullcontent">

<div id="quarto-content" class="page-columns page-rows-contents page-layout-article">

<main class="content" id="quarto-document-content">

<header id="title-block-header" class="quarto-title-block default">
<div class="quarto-title">
<h1 class="title">Latex equations in Quarto</h1>
</div>



<div class="quarto-title-meta">

    
  
    
  </div>
  

</header>

<p><span class="math display">\[
Pr(A) = 0.5 \\
Pr(B) = 0.5
\]</span></p>

</main>
<!-- /main column -->
<script id="quarto-html-after-body" type="application/javascript">
window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  const toggleBodyColorMode = (bsSheetEl) => {
    const mode = bsSheetEl.getAttribute("data-mode");
    const bodyEl = window.document.querySelector("body");
    if (mode === "dark") {
      bodyEl.classList.add("quarto-dark");
      bodyEl.classList.remove("quarto-light");
    } else {
      bodyEl.classList.add("quarto-light");
      bodyEl.classList.remove("quarto-dark");
    }
  }
  const toggleBodyColorPrimary = () => {
    const bsSheetEl = window.document.querySelector("link#quarto-bootstrap");
    if (bsSheetEl) {
      toggleBodyColorMode(bsSheetEl);
    }
  }
  toggleBodyColorPrimary();  
  const icon = "";
  const anchorJS = new window.AnchorJS();
  anchorJS.options = {
    placement: 'right',
    icon: icon
  };
  anchorJS.add('.anchored');
  const clipboard = new window.ClipboardJS('.code-copy-button', {
    target: function(trigger) {
      return trigger.previousElementSibling;
    }
  });
  clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    // button target
    const button = e.trigger;
    // don't keep focus
    button.blur();
    // flash "checked"
    button.classList.add('code-copy-button-checked');
    var currentTitle = button.getAttribute("title");
    button.setAttribute("title", "Copied!");
    let tooltip;
    if (window.bootstrap) {
      button.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "tooltip");
      button.setAttribute("data-bs-placement", "left");
      button.setAttribute("data-bs-title", "Copied!");
      tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(button, 
        { trigger: "manual", 
          customClass: "code-copy-button-tooltip",
          offset: [0, -8]});
      tooltip.show();    
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (tooltip) {
        tooltip.hide();
        button.removeAttribute("data-bs-title");
        button.removeAttribute("data-bs-toggle");
        button.removeAttribute("data-bs-placement");
      }
      button.setAttribute("title", currentTitle);
      button.classList.remove('code-copy-button-checked');
    }, 1000);
    // clear code selection
    e.clearSelection();
  });
  function tippyHover(el, contentFn) {
    const config = {
      allowHTML: true,
      content: contentFn,
      maxWidth: 500,
      delay: 100,
      arrow: false,
      appendTo: function(el) {
          return el.parentElement;
      },
      interactive: true,
      interactiveBorder: 10,
      theme: 'quarto',
      placement: 'bottom-start'
    };
    window.tippy(el, config); 
  }
  const noterefs = window.document.querySelectorAll('a[role="doc-noteref"]');
  for (var i=0; i<noterefs.length; i++) {
    const ref = noterefs[i];
    tippyHover(ref, function() {
      // use id or data attribute instead here
      let href = ref.getAttribute('data-footnote-href') || ref.getAttribute('href');
      try { href = new URL(href).hash; } catch {}
      const id = href.replace(/^#\/?/, "");
      const note = window.document.getElementById(id);
      return note.innerHTML;
    });
  }
  const findCites = (el) => {
    const parentEl = el.parentElement;
    if (parentEl) {
      const cites = parentEl.dataset.cites;
      if (cites) {
        return {
          el,
          cites: cites.split(' ')
        };
      } else {
        return findCites(el.parentElement)
      }
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  };
  var bibliorefs = window.document.querySelectorAll('a[role="doc-biblioref"]');
  for (var i=0; i<bibliorefs.length; i++) {
    const ref = bibliorefs[i];
    const citeInfo = findCites(ref);
    if (citeInfo) {
      tippyHover(citeInfo.el, function() {
        var popup = window.document.createElement('div');
        citeInfo.cites.forEach(function(cite) {
          var citeDiv = window.document.createElement('div');
          citeDiv.classList.add('hanging-indent');
          citeDiv.classList.add('csl-entry');
          var biblioDiv = window.document.getElementById('ref-' + cite);
          if (biblioDiv) {
            citeDiv.innerHTML = biblioDiv.innerHTML;
          }
          popup.appendChild(citeDiv);
        });
        return popup.innerHTML;
      });
    }
  }
});
</script>
</div> <!-- /content -->



</body></html>
```

Comment: In real latex your syntax would be invalid and one would use e.g. an `align` environment to create a multi-line formula. I've no idea if your syntax would be valid in mathjax, but if I look at the resulting html file, I do get a line break https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHhZN.png Can you share your html file so we can check if it is a problem with converting to html or with your browser?

Comment: Hi @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Thank you for your comment! I added the html file above, thanks!

Comment: With your html file, I also don't see a line break. With Quarto v1.3.49 and pandoc v3.1.1 I get very different code.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74263473/alignment-and-numbering-of-equations-in-html) work for you?

Comment: Hi @Julian, Thank you for your suggestion! Yes that could be an option, but the problem with that is that it automatically adds numbers to each equation which I don't actually need. Do you know a workaround for that? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just use an asterix, e.g. `\align{*}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `align` latex environment, e.g.

```
---
title: "Latex equations in Quarto"
format:
  html:
    html-math-method: mathjax
---

\begin{align*}
Pr(A) &= 0.5 \\
Pr(B) &= 0.5
\end{align*}
```

[image]